# keydown event cannot be listened correctly

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

My codes:

```
<div id="queryPage">
        <div id="queryToolbar" class="row" style="display: block;">
            <div id="query-option-panel" class="col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-offset-1">
            </div>
        </div>


        <div id="queryModal" class="modal fade" style="display: none;">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                    <form role="form" method="GET" class="query-form form-horizontal" id="query-form" style="display: block;">
                      ...

        <div id="screen" class="Screen"></div>
    </div>
```

My backbone View:

```
module.exports = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: 'div',
  events: {
    'click #saveReportBtn': '_handleSaveReport',
    'click #saveQuery': '_handleSaveQuery',
    'keydown #queryToolbar': '_enter',
  },
  _enter( event ) {
    console.log('event target:', + event.target.name + ', ' + event.currentTarget.name); // eslint-disable-line no-console
  },
...
```

keypress event supposed to be listened by #queryToolbar, but why **only** when #query-form poped up, it can be captured.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

My codes:

```
  events: {
    'keydown': '_enter',
  },


  _enter( event ) {
    console.log('event target:', + event.target.name + ', ' + event.currentTarget.name); // eslint-disable-line no-console
    if ( event.keyCode === 13 ) {
      console.log('enter key down'); // eslint-disable-line no-console
    }
    if ( this._getReportId() > 0 ) {
      console.log('save query'); // eslint-disable-line no-console
    } else {
      console.log('save report'); // eslint-disable-line no-console
    }
  },
```

**When query-form popped up (pic 1), I can see the log in console (pic2). but when query-form not popped up, when enter key down, I cannot see anything. Confused.**

pic1:
[image]

pic2:
[image]

Comment: `_enter( event ) {` needs to be `_enter: function( event ) {`

Comment: The code you've posted contains syntax errors, as pointed out by others. Please correct those first.

Comment: @AndréDion which line?

Comment: The prototype object you're feeding into `Backbone.View.extend()` is invalid. `_enter` needs a key: `_enter: function(event) { ... }`.

Comment: @AndréDion Please see my updates. I have no idea _enter need the key. and I tried the answer by utkarsh below, but not work.

Comment: @AndréDion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36944300/keyword-function-is-necessary-in-the-following-codes/36944939#36944939

Comment: Please don't duplicate questions...

Comment: do you think they are same questions?

Answer (score 0):

Write your event handler as following

```
_enter: function(event){
    console.log('event target:', + event.target.name + ', ' + event.currentTarget.name); // eslint-disable-line no-console
}
```

Right now what you are doing is just calling a function which you have never defined.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not the reason. when #query-form poped up, I can see the log in console.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36944300/keyword-function-is-necessary-in-the-following-codes/36944939#36944939

Comment: Please create JS fiddle for your problem