# keyword function is necessary in the following codes:

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

My backbone View:

```
module.exports = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: 'div',
  events: {
    'click #saveReportBtn': '_handleSaveReport',
    'click #saveQuery': '_handleSaveQuery',
    'keydown #queryToolbar': '_enter',
  },
  _enter( event ) {
    console.log('event target:', + event.target.name + ', ' + event.currentTarget.name); // eslint-disable-line no-console
  },
...
```

Some people suggested to use:

```
  _enter: function ( event ) {
    console.log('event target:', + event.target.name + ', ' + event.currentTarget.name); // eslint-disable-line no-console
  },
```

But it seems that it works without function keyword, and my eslint complains:

```
src/myfile.js
  100:11  warning  Missing function expression name  func-names

✖ 1 problem (0 errors, 1 warning)
```

Anything missing?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shorthand you are using:

```
_enter( event ) {
    console.log('event target:', + event.target.name + ', ' + event.currentTarget.name); // eslint-disable-line no-console
  }
```

Is ES2015 (ES6) shorthand which is why eslint doesn't complain.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions

Specifically:

> Note : The shorthand syntax uses named function instead of anonymous functions (as in …foo: function() {}…).

Try adding a function name to your assignment. (http://eslint.org/docs/rules/func-names)

```
 _enter: function _enter( event ) {
    console.log('event target:', + event.target.name + ', ' + event.currentTarget.name); // eslint-disable-line no-console
  }
```

Having named functions, rather than anonymous functions floating around really help with the debugging process and more explicit stack traces

Comment: But why _enter( event ) {} works? function keyword missing.

Comment: I believe (could be wrong) _enter(event){} is a short hand for the function I posted above.

Comment: Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions

Comment: Edited my answer to expand on es2015

Comment: Thanks. It seems  that I have to learn a lot in the future to become frontend developer.

Comment: Please keep in mind that this syntax is not yet supported by IE and Safari.

Comment: @РоманПарадеев Thanks. I will test them under safari.